# android retrofit post request request body as raw JSON

Tags: android, retrofit

This is my first time using the retrofit in android (Java) and i don't know how to do post api

in postman i use Request Body as raw JSON

{
"description": "aaaaaa",
"reportedpriority_description": "Elevé",
"reportedby": "zz",
"assetnum": "111",
"affectedperson": "ahmed"
}

someone can help me with example of code? it return empty response body

Answer (score 1):

```
  void requestcall(){
         try
            {
               
                HashMap respMap = new HashMap<>();
                respMap.put("Key1", "Value1");
                respMap.put("Key2", "Value2");
                respMap.put("Key3", "Value3");
                String resultString = convertToJson(respMap);
                sendToServer(resultString);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            { }
    }
    
       public static String convertToJson(HashMap<String, String> respMap)
        {
            JSONObject respJson = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject respDetsJson = new JSONObject();
            Iterator mapIt = respMap.entrySet().iterator();
    
            try
            {
                while (mapIt.hasNext()) {
                    HashMap.Entry<String, String> entry = (HashMap.Entry) mapIt.next();
                    respDetsJson.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                }
                //change according to your response
                respJson.put("RESPONSE", respDetsJson);
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                return  "";
            }
    
            return respJson.toString();
        }
```

Comment: and how i will use this method requestcall? where i insert the baseurl ?

Comment: are not you using retrofit for networking??

Comment: Yes just show me please how to appel those methods.. in the interface @Body entered as map??

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can send a body for Post methods, you can either create a JSON string in the format you want. Or you can simply create a model class with the same field names as your JSON keys, and then initialize values to them while sending a request.

Model class:

```
class Example {

var description: String? = null
var reportedpriority_description: String? = null
var reportedby: String? = null
var assetnum: String? = null
var affectedperson: String? = null
}
```

Init values:

```
val obj = Example()
obj.description = "aaaaaa"
// and so on
```

You can then pass the object to your POST method.

You can refer to [documentations](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) to learn how to code the API methods.

Hope this works for you!